# jQuery Autocomplete display results containing all searched terms cumulative

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm trying to implement an autocomplete using jquery.
Everything is ok for entire words, but for sepatare pieces, is not working.
For example if my data contain:
1) my blue car
2) my favourite car
3) my favourite red car

I need if I type "car" and "red" to be returned only last data "my favourite red car"
I used  term.split(' ') but in this case the result will contain all three records because all are containg "car", but I need to display only the last record which are containing all searched terms.
Could you help me please?
Thanks

my code:

```
var dateintroVar = [
{  labbel: 'my blue car', value: 'my blue car', data: '1'},
{  labbel: 'my favourite car', value: 'my favourite car', data: '2'},
{  labbel: 'my favourite red car', value: 'my favourite red car', data: '3'}
```

];

```
$(function() {
$( "#campcompl" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: dateintroVar,
    focus: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#campcompl" ).val( ui.item.labbel);
    $( "#txt1b" ).val( ui.item.data );
    return false;
},
select: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#campcompl" ).val( ui.item.labbel);
    $( "#txt1b" ).val( ui.item.data );
    return false;
 }
})
.autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
  return $( "<li>" )
 .append( "<a>" + item.labbel + "</a>" )
 .appendTo( ul );
};
```

});

And modified in jquery-ui.js:

```
    filter: function(array, term) { var matcher;    var keys = term.split(' ');
        $.each(keys, function(index, value) {       
matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(value), "i" ); });      
return $.grep( array, function(value) {     
    return matcher.test( value.label || value.value || value );
                }); }
```

Comment: Can you show your existing code?

Comment: any suggestion, please...

Comment: You would need fuzzy matching which isn't supported by jQuery autocomplete. You can override it and use your own code to do the match. As shown here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19084976/jquery-autocomplete-matching-multiple-unordered-words-in-a-string

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion , but in that example are selected all records with each separated word, not only that which contain all words, indifferent by their order...